# Выполнение системой событий qt

Tags: qt, c++

пишу клиент серверное приложение на qt - программа удаленного доступа к компьютеру. Подскажите, в каком виде отсылать события, совершенные на клиенте(клики, нажатия клавиш) на сервер, и как сделать так, чтобы сервер их выполнял, соответственно не в QMainWindow а реально на рабочем столе?

Comment: @Ann Boichenko пожалуйста укажите в метках язык программирования. Qt как известно не язык программирования, а инструмент

Comment: >а реально на рабочем столе

Можно поконкретнее, что хотите получить?

Comment: хочу получить, чтобы события обрабатывались не в самом окне приложения, а именно чтобы они обрабатывались системой

Comment: в целом а не в самом приложении

Comment: Ну это все равно придется писать какое-то приложение-сервер,которое будет принимать сигналы от удаленного клиента и отправлять системе.

Comment: так вооот, допустим вообразим что сигналы то он принимает. вопрос в том, каким боком их системе отправлять?

Comment: Смотря какая система. Если Линукс - то через системные вызовы и через функции X Window для работы с графической оболочкой

Comment: а где это почитать можно или примеры посмотреть? а то я вообще если честно не понимаю о чем речь. и да, мне именно на линуксе...

Comment: Почитайте про такую вещь как VNC

Answer (score 3):

надо задачу разбить на простые независимые части:

1. генерация движение мыши и нажатия клавы (под виндой знаю key_event mouth_event, мог бы помочь, под линуксом нет, но думаю мануал найти нетрудно под конкретную оболочку).
2. Система текстовых команд с параметрами для управления (например сценарий из текстового файла или из консоли)
3. Передача тех же команд по tcp/ip, читка сервером и отправка генератору движений
4. отправка изображения экрана (обратно)

(а вообще же я видел такую програмку в линуксе, под виндой в удаленном линуксе печатал, только она с русским текстом глючила)

P.S. Не думаю, что в QT есть кроссплатформенные средства генерации событий мыши и клавиатуры, если кто найдет будет интересно